# C STREAM client socket reuse after disconnecting

Tags: c, sockets

How should I disconnect a stream socket from server so that I will be able to use socket to connect it to different address again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just [`close(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/close.html) the socket and create it again using [`socket(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/socket.html).